# ソフト起動時にCドライブ直下のSaveFile.txtを読み込みたい

Tags: c++

現在、embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

ソフトを起動時にCドライブ直下のSaveFile.txtを読み込みたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

```
void __fastcall TTCP_Client::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{

    if(FileExists("c:/SaveFile.txt"))
        ADODataSet1->LoadFromFile("c:/SaveFile.txt");
    else
        StatusBar1->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Save file does not exist!";

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

このようなコードにしたのですが、ビルドは成功するのですが、デバッグしていくとエラーがでて停止してしまいます。実行でも停止します。
エラー回避方法はどのようにしたらよいですか？

デバッグが停止してしまう時のエラー：

> デバッガ例外通知
>   プロジェクトTCPClient.exe は例外クラス EOLeException (メッセージ '指定されたソースから Recordset を作成できません。ソース ファイルまたはストリームの Recordset データは XML あるいは ADTG 形式である必要があります。') を検出しました。

[image: デバッグが停止してしまう時のエラー]

Cドライブ直下に置いたSaveFile.txtの内容：

```
BKUK12
BKUK34
BKUK56
BKUK78
```

[image: Cドライブ直下に置いたSaveFile.txtの内容]

Comment: エラーとはどういうエラーが出るんでしょうか。

Comment: 今画像を追加してみたんですが、”デバッガ例外通知”というエラーボックスが出てきました。

Comment: どーみてもファイル読み込みでエラーでてるんではなくて、呼び出し元に問題がありそうな感じだけど

Comment: 「Recordset を作成できません。 Recordset データは XML あるいは ADTG 形式である必要があります。」と エラーメッセージになっていますね。 テキスト形式の中身に問題があるのではありませんか？

Comment: [ファイルからのデータ読み込みとファイルへのデータ保存 - RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98) 「データは、ADTG または XML という 2 つの独自形式のいずれかで保存されます。ADO でサポートされているのは、この 2 つのファイル形式だけです。」とのこと。

Comment: (文字数オーバーしたので) ADTGは「Advanced Data TableGram」の略だそうです( [レコードセットの永続化に関する詳細情報 | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/more-about-recordset-persistence) )

Comment: 今Cドライブ直下に置いたSaveFile.txtの内容の画像を追加しました。

Comment: みなさん回答頂きありがとうございます。sublime textでXMLファイルが出力できると聞いたのですが、save asとかでXML形式が見当たらないのですが、MACとかでXMLファイル出力できる方法とかありますでしょうか？

Comment: 画像を貼り付けるのでなく、文字で記載してください。スタックオーバーフローはQ&Aの蓄積を目的としているため、画像ではググラビリティが低下します。

Comment: SaveFile.txt を作成したプログラムの方を修正するべきだと思います。ADTG または XML 形式で 保存するように修正してください。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。xmlファイルとか扱ったことがないのですが、自動で作成してくれるエディタソフトとかフリーでありませんか？

Comment: もしくは、単純にtxtファイルを読み込めるコンポーネントはRAD Studioにはありますでしょうか？

Comment: 質問内容がずれてきているように見受けられます。答えて欲しいことを再考し、質問文およびタイトルを修正してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。
とりあえずこちらのファイル入力機能で現在は十分と感じましたので、内容を変更しました。

```
using namespace std;

void __fastcall TTCP_Client::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{

    #if 0
    if(FileExists("c:/SaveFile.xml"))
        ADODataSet1->LoadFromFile("c:/SaveFile.xml");
    else
        StatusBar1->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Save file does not exist!";
    #endif

    AnsiString filename = "c:/SaveFile.txt";

    //filename += ".csv";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

    if( !(fin.fail()) )
    {
        string line;
        getline(fin, line);
        AnsiString str(line.c_str());
        ShowMessage(str);
    }

}
```

https://github.com/KenjiMaehara/CppChatTCP/blob/3270c6ef1c0baa2b35e905a8dbb1ecc2cd114065/TCPClient/Unit1.cpp

Comment: Vista 以後、一般ユーザーは `C:\` にファイルを生成する権限を持っていない（デフォルトでは）ので、移行前ソフトがそういう仕様だからと言って忠実に移植するとあとで困りますよ。時勢に合わせて適宜見直しが必要でしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: あれ円マークが見えないっすね、コメント欄ではメタ文字なのかな？　C：￥　っす。