# 読み込んだファイルのテキストすべてを表示させたい。

Tags: c++

現在、embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

[以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60697/35993) で、テキストファイルを読み込むことができましたが、テキストファイル内には文字列が4行入っており、表示されたメッセージボックスには最初の1行目の文字列の”testtest12”のみが表示されるだけです。

残りの4行もすべてメッセージボックスに表示させるにはどのようにプログラムしたらよいでしょうか？
どうぞ、よろしくお願いします。

```
void __fastcall TTCP_Client::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{

    AnsiString filename = "SaveFile.txt";

    //filename += ".csv";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

    if( !(fin.fail()) )
    {
        string line;
        getline(fin, line);
        AnsiString str(line.c_str());
        ShowMessage(str);
    }
    else
    {
        StatusBar1->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Save file does not exist!";
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/JA/html/delphivclwin32/Dialogs_ShowMessage.html によると渡されたテキストを表示するので、当然なのでは？（今のコードは１行分しか渡していないわけなので）

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[C++ 最後までファイルを読む](https://riptutorial.com/ja/cplusplus/example/25173/%E6%9C%80%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%80), [C++でファイルを読み込むシンプルな例](https://www.miraclelinux.com/tech-blog/1n4hgx), [C++でファイル読込み パターン別まとめ](https://fa11enprince.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/03/233500)

Comment: 全行読んで表示すりゃいいには御意なのですが `ShowMessage()` が改行あり文字列に対応しているか、していても @nordsynth 氏の希望どおりに表示するかはわからないしってことで、あの程度のコメントに留めた次第。

Comment: その場合は次の質問がされるでしょう。少し先回りしておくとこんな記事が参考に。[ShowMessage で複数行メッセージを表示](http://www2.ttcn.ne.jp/~tkky/Tips/Message/showmessage1.htm), [c++ builder XE4, 10.2 Tokyo > String > 複数行Stringを降順にする](https://qiita.com/7of9/items/6d1933eac7ccd89a5246)

Comment: 資料サイトありがとうございます。coutに出す方法でとりあえずやってみてるのですが、ビルド成功しているのですが、実行した際にcoutに出てくるのは”出力”の画面でしょうか？

Comment: このページ [旧C++Builder FAQ - プログラミング・VCL(1)](https://support.embarcadero.com/article/37499) の真ん中へんに「GUIアプリ上での標準出力を使用するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか」というのがあるので参考に。あと、回答では無く、質問に追記した方が良いですよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。GUIアプリの場合はcoutの結果はファイル出力で確認できるのですね。助かります。

Comment: [`<<`はストリームへの出力](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string/op_ostream.html)なので、出力先が文字列の場合には使えないのでは？ 単純に連結したいなら、上の [c++ builder XE4, 10.2 Tokyo > String > 複数行Stringを降順にする](https://qiita.com/7of9/items/6d1933eac7ccd89a5246) のように`+`で足していけば良いのでは？

Answer (score -2, accepted):

とりあえず、ShowMessageで読み込んだファイルのテキストを出力できました。
ShowMessageでエラー出ていましたが、AnsiString str(line02.c_str());を追加することで解決しました。AnsiString型に渡してやらないとエラーが回避できないのがよくわからない感じです（＾＾；

```
using namespace std;

void __fastcall TTCP_Client::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{

    AnsiString filename = "SaveFile.txt";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

    if( !(fin.fail()) )
    {
        string line;
        string line02;

        while(getline(fin,line))
        {
            //cout << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
            //line02 << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
            line = "[" + line;
            line = line + "]\r\n";
            line02 = line02 + line;


        }

        AnsiString str(line02.c_str());
        ShowMessage(str);
    }
    else
    {
        StatusBar1->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Save file does not exist!";
    }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;    これも表示していないでした。

Comment: GUI アプリケーションの `stdout` がどこに接続されているかは微妙で、少なくとも VS2005 の MFC においては cout に出力した文字は簡単には確認できません。素直にデバッガでウオッチするのが早そうな気がします。ってか `ShowMessage("Alpha\nBravo\nCharie\n");` とかしてみたらいいんでないっすか？

Comment: VisualStudioだとテクニックがあるようですね。[Visual C++でデバッグ時の出力をIDE(Visual Studio)上に出す方法](https://fa11enprince.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/07/04/192645) RAD studioにもあるのかもしれませんが、ファイル出力の方が先にヒットしたのでそちらを紹介しておきました。

Comment: 一応、自分としてほしかった動作を実現はできたのですが、getlineなどの動作をもっとよく知りたいと思っていて、RAD Studioのデバッグ機能でこの部分のコードをステップで追いたいと思ったのですが、必ず”Abnomal program termination”というエラーがでてRAD Studioごと強制終了してしまう現象がおきているのですが、この辺のコードでは仕方ないことでしょうか？

Comment: `cout` や `getline` の話は別質問にてどうぞ。デバッガやコンパイラが異常終了するのは、普通にはありえなくて、おかしいです。