# RAD Studio でのデバッグで Abnormal program termination が必ず発生する

Tags: c++, rad-studio

現在、RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

exeファイルと同じディレクトリ内のSaveFile.txtを読み込むプログラムをデバッグする時に、ステップ実行していくと必ず”Abnormal program termination”が発生して、RAD Studioごと強制終了してしまうのですが、回避方法などはありませんでしょうか？

下のプログラムで、最初の行からステップ実行していくと、”string line;”の宣言のところで出てきます。

また、”string line;”を一番最初のステップに変えても起こります。
なにかstring型の宣言と関係はありますでしょうか？

こちらのGitHubサイトに[コード](https://github.com/KenjiMaehara/CppChatTCP/commit/d47a550bae17680d0b6fe46fcf069d944309545c)がありますが、RAD Studioをお持ちの方で同様の現象は発生していますでしょうか？

```
using namespace std;

void __fastcall TTCP_Client::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{

    AnsiString filename = "SaveFile.txt";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

    if( !(fin.fail()) )
    {
        string line;
        string line02;

        while(getline(fin,line))
        {
            //cout << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
            //line02 << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
            line = "[" + line;
            line = line + "]\r\n";
            line02 = line02 + line;
        }

        AnsiString str(line02.c_str());
        ShowMessage(str);
    }
    else
    {
        StatusBar1->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Save file does not exist!";
    }

}
```

Comment: コンパイルは正常に通っているのでしょうか？また、デバッグでは無く通常実行の場合はどうなりますか？ / 「exeファイルと同じディレクトリ内のファイル」とありますが、過去の関連質問でのコメントで [権限に注意しましょう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60697/%e3%82%bd%e3%83%95%e3%83%88%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e6%99%82%e3%81%abc%e3%83%89%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%96%e7%9b%b4%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%aesavefile-txt%e3%82%92%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%81%bf%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment65824_60716) というアドバイスがありましたが、この辺は大丈夫でしょうか。

Comment: ビルド結果は警告、エラー共に0です。また、読み込みのファイルは、以前はCドライブ直下にしていましたが、現在はexeファイルと同ディレクトリに変更しています。

Comment: それと、通常の実行では問題なく動作しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本日、RAD Studio のアップデートで 10.3.3 を再インストールしたところ、今回の現象はなくなり、デバッグできるようになりました。
原因は不明です。私の最初のインストール方法が悪かったのかもしれないです。
助かりました。